# OSM Bright Cartography XML

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, cartography, osm2pgsql

I have successfully setup a tile server as described here: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

What's troubling is the lack of clarify surrounding OSM Bright and default styles.

I've followed the documentation as described, I've managed to install TileMill and MapBox Studio, but I cannot seem to find a precompiled stylesheet that somewhat resembles the default look of openstreetmaps.org.

Following the directions for OSM Bright, I get a map of continents and oceans.  Does a precompiled XML file that works with mapnik exist which handles more than continents and oceans?

I had to delete many  xml nodes as they were throwing errors when attempting to run renderd and I'm assuming these XML nodes described the features I'd like to see styled.

Can anyone elaborate on how these components fit together and what I am doing wrong/not seeing?  Please point me toward some resouce(s) that further explains how I can compile a default streetmap with basic styles for a North American dataset.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright/blob/master/osm-bright/base.mss mss to xml in tilemill